# EKReminder error when creating on OS X: No calendar has been set

Tags: macos, sandbox, eventkit

I have a snippet of code that is attempting to save a generic reminder, using the `EventKit` framework in OS X 10.8 and newer. Here is my code snippet:

```
NSLog(@"Creating reminder.");
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskReminder];
NSLog(@"Auth status: %lu", [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder]);

[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Granted: %d Error: %@", granted, error);
    if (granted) {
        EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];
        reminder.title = @"My Reminder";
        EKCalendar *reminderCalendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder eventStore:eventStore];
        NSLog(@"Using EKCalendar: %@", reminderCalendar);
        reminder.calendar = reminderCalendar;

        NSError *commitError = nil;
        if (![eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&commitError] || commitError) {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred committing the reminder: %@", commitError);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Reminder created successfully.");
        }
    }
}];
```

And here is the output I see:

```
2014-01-08 19:56:21.182 MyApp[6073:303] Creating reminder.
2014-01-08 19:56:21.358 MyApp[6073:303] Auth status: 3
2014-01-08 19:56:21.358 MyApp[6073:3423] Granted: 1 Error: (null)
2014-01-08 19:56:21.359 MyApp[6073:3423] Using EKCalendar: EKCalendar <0x9c430>, calendarIdentifier:9BD66DA9-014D-4918-849A-1D6763994511, allowEvents:0, allowReminders:1, allowsContentModifications:1, isSubscribed:0, isDeletable:1, isRenameable:1, isShareable:0, defaultOrganizerIsMeForNewItems:0
2014-01-08 19:56:21.366 MyApp[6073:3423] An error occurred committing the reminder: Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x60000067d900 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}
```

However, despite the error message, the `EKCalendar` has been successfully created/accessed, *and* set on the `EKReminder` object.

The only other similar resources I've found for this error occur when using `EventKit` on iOS, in which the method for gaining access is slightly different.

According to this Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html

> You can create reminders using the reminderWithEventStore: class
>   method. The title and calendar properties are required. The calendar
>   for a reminder is the list with which it is grouped.

But I must be doing something wrong. Under my `App Sandbox/App Data` permissions, I have selected both `Calendar` and `Contacts` just to be safe, but the error seems unrelated to permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
EKCalendar *reminderCalendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder eventStore:eventStore];
NSLog(@"Using EKCalendar: %@", reminderCalendar);
reminder.calendar = reminderCalendar;
```

I was able to create the `EKReminder` successfully using:

```
reminder.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];
```